# Injectivity, Linear Transformations

Tags: linear-algebra

Considering the linear map $f: X\rightarrow Y$ and $g: Y\rightarrow Z$

If $g(f(x))$ is injective, then are $g$ and $f$ injective (respectively)?

My Answer:

Is $g$ injective?
$g(f(x))$ injective implies that $g(f(x))=0$ only when $x = 0$, but then $f(0)$ is 0 by linearity, which implies that the kernel of $g$ is 0, therefore $g$ is injective.

Is $f$ injective?
I claim $f$ is injective, for if it were not, then there would be some non-zero $x$ such that $f(x)=0$, thus by linearity $g(f(x)) =g(0)=0$ for non-zero $x$, contradicting the idea that $g\circ f$ is injective.

Is this correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}^2$ defined by $f(x)=(x,0)$ and $g:\mathbb{R^2}\to\mathbb{R}$ defined by $g(x,y)=x$ ? Note that $g\circ f=\mathrm{Id}_\mathbb{R}$ is one-to-one so injective, but $g(1,1)=g(1,0)=1$ so $g$ is not injective.

The good result is that $g\circ f$ injective implies $f$ injective only. Indeed, $x\in\ker f$ implies that $x\in\ker g\circ f=\{0\}$ and so $\ker f=\{0\}.$